# Play2 - form -> objectId

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, morphia, objectid

I have a problem with the forms in play2.

Model:

```
@Id private ObjectId id;
```

Form

```
<input name="id" id="id" type="hidden" value="@guidesForm.field("id").value()">
```

I can not initialize the id field with `bindFromRequest()` it will always be empty. And I can only query with an ObjectId not with a string.

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId(form().bindFromRequest().get("id"));
```

This is the correct constructor for an objectid. As you can see this is my workaround I don't use `guideForm.bindFromRequest();` I just have to bind it directly.

This feels a bit hacky. Is a soltuion where i just can use the normal binding?

```
Form<Myclass> guideForm = form(Myclass.class);
Form<Myclass> filledForm = guideForm.bindFromRequest();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to register a custom DataBinder in the onStart() of the [Global object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/JavaGlobal):

```
Formatters.register(ObjectId.class, new SimpleFormatter<ObjectId>() {

    @Override
    public ObjectId parse(String input, Locale l) throws ParseException {

        return ...; // create the object from the input of the form
    }

    @Override
    public String print(ObjectId objectId, Locale l) {
        return String.valueOf(objectId.id);
    }

});
```

The doc is available at the end of this page: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/JavaForms